# failed to load listeners: can't create unix socket /var/run/docker.sock: device or resource busy gitlab-runner

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-in-docker

Im running docker in docker gitlab-runner. my pipeline was working fine and suddenly the next day I get this error

```
2023-08-22T12:16:21.520946073Z time="2023-08-22T12:16:21.520554728Z" level=info msg="Starting up"
2023-08-22T12:16:21.521733410Z time="2023-08-22T12:16:21.521587541Z" level=warning msg="Binding to IP address without --tlsverify is insecure and gives root access on this machine to everyone who has access to your network." host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
2023-08-22T12:16:21.521765153Z time="2023-08-22T12:16:21.521610008Z" level=warning msg="Binding to an IP address, even on localhost, can also give access to scripts run in a browser. Be safe out there!" host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
2023-08-22T12:16:22.522290320Z time="2023-08-22T12:16:22.521953700Z" level=warning msg="Binding to an IP address without --tlsverify is deprecated. Startup is intentionally being slowed down to show this message" host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
2023-08-22T12:16:22.522367162Z time="2023-08-22T12:16:22.522079166Z" level=warning msg="Please consider generating tls certificates with client validation to prevent exposing unauthenticated root access to your network" host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
2023-08-22T12:16:22.522385980Z time="2023-08-22T12:16:22.522118385Z" level=warning msg="You can override this by explicitly specifying '--tls=false' or '--tlsverify=false'" host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
2023-08-22T12:16:22.522402142Z time="2023-08-22T12:16:22.522148075Z" level=warning msg="Support for listening on TCP without authentication or explicit intent to run without authentication will be removed in the next release" host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
2023-08-22T12:16:37.535125199Z time="2023-08-22T12:16:37.534854215Z" level=warning msg="could not change group /var/run/docker.sock to docker: group docker not found"
2023-08-22T12:16:37.538601295Z failed to load listeners: can't create unix socket /var/run/docker.sock: device or resource busy
```

this is my gitlab-runner config.toml

```
concurrent = 5
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0
log_level = "trace"

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "Awesome Docker Runner"
  url = "https://gitlab-site/"
  id = 10855
  token = "some token"
  token_obtained_at = 2022-01-24T07:07:59Z
  token_expires_at = some-date
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "muycustome-docker-runner"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = [
      "/cache",
      "/opt/.docker/config.json:/root/.docker/config.json:ro",
      "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    ]
    extra_hosts = ["cache-registry.io:Ip-for-registery"]
    pull_policy = ["always"]
    shm_size = 0
```

sneak peak on gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - build

variables:
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  
  IMAGE_HOST: cache-registry.io
  
services:
  - name: muycustome-docker-runner
    alias: docker

default:
  tags:
    - dind
  image: muycustome-docker-runner
  before_script:
    - docker info
```

I have tried a few things but it still not working.

1. Reboot the gitlab-runner VM obviously
2. Checked if docker group is created and gitlab-runner user is in the group
3. Updated the gitlab-runner version to match gitlab
4. Restarted docker
5. Checked if /var/run/docker.sock was locked
6. removed dind gitlab-ci.yml
7. tried to make sense of the logs in gitlab-runner but the issue seems to be in the custom docker itself

Comment: It feels counterintuitive to mount docker.sock from the host to the container then tag this gitlab runner with "dind" (it is not docker-in-docker, it is using host docker) and then also run a service. Do you want to run dind _or_ do you want to use host docker? `day I get this error` _Where_ do you get this error? Please post full log. `if /var/run/docker.sock was locked` What does it mean if ta file is locked? What commands exactly did you execute and what is the exact output of the commands.

Comment: /var/run/docker.sock was not locked. and yes perhaps its not dind , the tag is not required as im using a custom docker runner image. but even with removing the tag its still same issues. reference /var/run/docker.sock [link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-the-docker-executor-with-docker-socket-binding).
Those that I showed are all the logs I have, the gitlab-runner logs doesn't show much information

Comment: I get the error when running my pipeline in gitlab :)

Answer (score 0):

gitlab-runner tries to create the sock file and found out it is already there
stop docker
remove the docker.sock file:
rm -f /var/run/docker.sock
and try again

Comment: that didn't work, required me to reinstall docker but still same issue